# Why css animation doesn't work with background size 100%

Tags: css, css-animations, css-sprites

I'm working with css animation with steps...my problem is:

- when step() == (frame length -1) everything is fluid exept that I can't see the last frame
- when step() == frame length I can't still see the last frame and animation is messy...

I'm looking for a way to use background 100% (or at least an explanation of why it doesn't work), for I can use it with sprites with differents number of frames and just use step() to adjust to the actual sprite..

Demo:

```css
#sprite1, #sprite2, #sprite3 {
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  background: url('https://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_756487pacanim2.png') 0 center;
}

#sprite1 {
  animation: sprite 1s steps(3) infinite;
}

#sprite2 {
  animation: sprite 1s steps(4) infinite;
}

#sprite3 {
  animation: sprite2 1s steps(4) infinite;
}


@keyframes sprite {
    100% { background-position: right center; }
}

@keyframes sprite2 {
    100% { background-position: 164px center; }
}
```

```html
Case1: <br>
<div id="sprite1"></div>
Case2:
<div id="sprite2"></div>
What it should be:
<div id="sprite3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required. Percentage of the animation duration.
Legal values:

0-100%
from (same as 0%)
to (same as 100%)

Note: You can have many keyframes-selectors in one animation.

sprit image 4 one start on 50% so i gave. check below sample code.

```css
#sprite1, #sprite2, #sprite3 {
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  background: url('https://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_756487pacanim2.png') 0 center;
}

#sprite1 {
  animation: sprite 1s steps(3) infinite;
}

#sprite2 {
  animation: sprite3 1s steps(3) infinite;
}

#sprite3 {
  animation: sprite2 1s steps(4) infinite;
}


@keyframes sprite {
    60% { background-position: right center; }
}

@keyframes sprite2 {
    100% { background-position: 164px center; }
}
@keyframes sprite3 {
    50% { background-position: right center; }
}
```

```html
Case1: <br>
<div id="sprite1"></div>
Case2:
<div id="sprite2"></div>
What it should be:
<div id="sprite3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, i edited my question, so is there a way I can use an animation keyframe compatible with all kind of spriteSheets (with just changing the step() value)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the initial position to be `background-position:-33% center;` instead of `background-position: 0 center;`

in this case the four steps will work like this:

- step1: `background-position: -33% center;` which will display img4
- step2: `background-position: 0% center;` which will display img1
- step3: `background-position: 33% center;`which will display img2
- step4: `background-position: 66% center;`which will display img3

```css
#sprite1 {
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  background: url('https://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_756487pacanim2.png') -33% center;
}
#sprite1 {
  animation: sprite 1s steps(4) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
    100% { background-position: right center; }
}
```

```html
<div id="sprite1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

10 = frames/steps;
For Edge you have to calculate the percentage;

```
@keyframes sprite{
  100%{
    background-position: calc(100% / (10 - 1) * 10) 0;
    background-position: 111.111% 0;/* Edge/IE */
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  animation: container 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes container {
  50% {
    width: 72px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}

#sprite {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xtk0SCC.png);
  background-position: 0% 0;
  background-size: calc(100% * 10) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: sprite 1s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  100% {
    background-position: calc(100% / (10 - 1) * 10) 0;
    background-position: 111.111% 0;/* Edge/IE */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="sprite"></div>
</div>
```